# Problem with Flashtool checksum

Tags: md5sum, data-corruption

I've downloaded the package flashtool-0.9.23.1-linux.tar.7z from http://www.flashtool.net/downloads_linux.php. As you can see, the MD5 hash is 3C70AF72F9B9E45C195F9192409E0C0F. This is the second download and when I check the value with md5sum I always get a68d331f710b78f7eaf4350e70d3e693.

Can anyone explain me why, as I don't think the file I have downloaded is always damaged? Someone told me that link points to an infected file, but it's hard for me to believe it, since it is the official download page. The Flashtool program seems to execute correctly on Ubuntu, but I want to be sure before flashing. Thanks.

Comment: either your download is corrupt or you ran the wrong command or the posted md5sum in incorrect. Post the command you ran to get the md5sum.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `md5sum <name-of-tar-file>`. I also obtain that hash code checking on Android with the md5checker app.

Comment: The file will take me over an hour to download so I am not willing to wait for the download. Post the command you ran to get the md5sum.

Comment: Well, either the download is corrupt or the posted md5sum is wrong. Cant tell without downloading the file or you can contact the person who posted the file in the first place. If you downloaded it more then once, and the md5sum is the same both times, then an incorrect listing of the md5um is most likely. Also download via a different method, ie change from http to torrent or the other way around.

Comment: I noticed that also the package for Windows gives a wrong md5.

Comment: You need to contact the package maintainer.

Comment: The author is unreachable, also on github. Do you think that all the md5's are wrong on the download page? That sounds very strange.. by the way I downloaded via torrent every time.

Comment: Post the git hub link. If the author is unreachable, and your believe the posted md5sum is correct, then by definition you have an altered download.

Comment: Download the file from github. It is a zip file , check the md5sum . extract the contents of both downloads and compair with diff - http://lifehacker.com/compare-the-contents-of-two-folders-with-the-diff-comma-598872057

Comment: This is what I get - ad6674b9797e92264c431f61723e57fb  Flashtool-master.zip . It would be unlikely we would get different md5sum on the same file if the download is corrupted.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that is the same md5 I founded on another download, a preceding version 0.9.22.3 from http://www.01net.com/telecharger/windows/Utilitaire/systeme/fiches/134900.html. Is it the same on github? ad6674b9797e92264c431f61723e57fb

Comment: I can not see that link, blocked as spam. The md5sum I posted is after downloading from github directly (which is what I would advise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the .zip file from git hub

https://github.com/Androxyde/Flashtool

My md5sum is

```
ad6674b9797e92264c431f61723e57fb Flashtool-master.zip
```

If you download from github and get the same md5um then I would say the zip from github is accurately downloaded.

If you then want to compair to what you have, extract both archives and compare them with the diff command

```
diff -r first_extraction second_sxtraction
```

changing first and second extraction to the location where you extracted the archives.

Comment: Thanks bodhi. Now I'm sure the preceding version is the correct one. Do you believe the most recent version (0.9.23.1) i.e. my first download whose md5 failed, contains some virus like someone told me?

Comment: You would have to extract it and use the diff command to see the differences. You could scan it with clam av.

Comment: yes of course. But the eventual virus would be for Windows, right? So no problem if I installed on my Ubuntu. Finally, about the github link you have given, can you tell me how can I download the zip? (which presumably is the same I downloaded from 01net.com.)

Comment: No problem, it was the mobile version of the page on my phone. Now with the desktop version I can get the download.

Comment: Click the green "clone or download" button